# creating a pyramide tiles of a geotiff using gdal

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a big geotiff file (about 300MB), and I saw an example of a big data organized in folders :

folder 0 contains one folder 0 which contains one .png file named 0.png

folder 1 contains two folders 0 and 1 and each one contain two pictures 0.png and 1.png

folder 2 contains four folders 0, 1, 2 and 3 each one contains four pictures ...

and I want to devide my geotiff like above. and I know that by usinggdal we can do it but I don't know how?

I tried this but it does not give a result

**gdaladdo -r average abc.tif 2 4 8 16**

Comment: Of course gdaladdo gives a result but the result is not what you thought. Your command is writing subsampled versions of abc.tif with 2, 4, 8, and 16 bigger pixel size than the original and saves them inside the same abc.tif image.

Comment: @user30184 please how can I get what I want? thank you

Comment: Did you try gdal2tiles? There is also a free version of MapTiler which is a further development of gdal2tiles http://www.maptiler.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the utility you are looking for is [gdal2tiles](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html):

```
gdal2tiles.py input_file output_dir
```